# Trouble aligning child menus with parent items

Tags: html, css

Hi im trying to create a navigation bar which when you hover the li another list come out from the side to show other options. My problem I can get to align with the first li but I'm not sure how to do it with the rest of the list. At the moment the drop down list stays in the same position.

Im sure I haven't explained it well enough here is my code.

```
<body class="menu">
<header>
    <nav class="menu-side">
    <ul>
              <li class="icon-home"><a href="Premiership.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>

            <li class="arrow"> <a  class="star" href="#">England</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="ee" href="Premiership.html">Premiership</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href= "Unavailble.html">Championship</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Unavailble.html">League 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Unavailble.html">League 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a  href="#">France</a>
                <ul >
                    <li id="r"><a class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">Ligue 1</a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Germany </a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">Bundesliga</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Italy</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">Serie A</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Spain</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a  class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">La Liga</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>    
    </nav>

    </header>


</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2zov6q2v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change margin of your lists:

```
nav ul ul {
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #399077;
    margin-left: 89.5%;
    //top: 9%; delete this line
    margin-top: -38px; //add this line
    z-index:150;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hg7pdtL1/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.menu-open {
  left: 0;
}
.menu-open .menu-side {
  left: 0;
}
.menu-side,
menu {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: left 0.2s ease;
  transition: left 0.2s ease;
}
.menu-side {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 210px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
}
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
nav ul {
  background-color: #43a286;
  /* overflow: hidden; <----------------- here */
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
  transition: max-height 0.4s;
}
nav ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative; /* <------------------ and here */
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #399077;
}
nav ul .arrow:hover {
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-right-width: thick;
  width: 79%;
}
nav ul ul {
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #399077;
  left: 89.5%;
  top: 9%;
  z-index: 150;
}
nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  width: 165px;
}
/*nav .ee:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid black;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px
} */

nav ul li a,
visited {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'CFJackStory-Regular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body class="menu">
  <header>
    <nav class="menu-side">
      <ul>
        <li class="icon-home"><a href="Premiership.html"><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="arrow"> <a class="star" href="#">England</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a class="ee" href="Premiership.html">Premiership</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Unavailble.html">Championship</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Unavailble.html">League 1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Unavailble.html">League 2</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">France</a>

          <ul>
            <li id="r"><a class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">Ligue 1</a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Germany </a>

          <ul>
            <li><a class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">Bundesliga</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Italy</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">Serie A</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Spain</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">La Liga</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Should probably change this: `top: 9%;` to `top:0;` also

Comment: Thought about that. Wasn't sure what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Change this style

```css
.menu{
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
 
}

.menu-open{
left: 0;


}

.menu-open .menu-side{
left: 0;

}

.menu-side, menu {
-webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: left 0.2s ease;
transition: left 0.2s ease;

}

.menu-side{
 background-color: #333;
 color: #fff;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 210px;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 2px;
}

body{
display: block;
 margin: 8px;
background: #f0f0f0;
}


nav ul{
    background-color: #43a286;
 color:white;
    padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
 -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
 -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
 transition: max-height 0.4s;
}

nav ul li{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #399077;
 
}

nav ul .arrow:hover{
border-right: 10px solid white;
border-right-width: thick;
width: 79%;
}

nav ul ul {
 height: auto;
 display: none;
 background-color: #399077;
 left: 212px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
 z-index:150;
}

nav ul ul li{
  display: block;
    width:75%;
 text-align: center;
}


nav ul li:hover ul{

   display: block;
      width: 165px;
}

/*nav .ee:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid black;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px
} */

nav ul li a, visited{
color:white;
font-family: 'CFJackStory-Regular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover{
color:white;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body class="menu">
<header>
 <nav class="menu-side">
 <ul>
     <li class="icon-home"><a href="Premiership.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
   
            <li class="arrow"> <a  class="star" href="#">England</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="ee" href="Premiership.html">Premiership</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href= "Unavailble.html">Championship</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Unavailble.html">League 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Unavailble.html">League 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a  href="#">France</a>
                <ul >
                    <li id="r"><a class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">Ligue 1</a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Germany </a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">Bundesliga</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Italy</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">Serie A</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="arrow"> <a href="#">Spain</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a  class="ee" href="Unavailble.html">La Liga</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>    
 </nav>
 
 </header>
 
 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

See this updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zov6q2v/16/).  Set `li`'s to `position: relative;` and `ul ul`'s to `position: absolute`.  From there you can set `ul ul`'s `left` to `100%`.  This pushes them all the way to the right of the parent.  You can use `left: calc(100% + 5px)` to account for `li`'s white right border when hovered. No need for messy margins.